# Running different App class in my application (for debug)

Tags: android, gradle

I want to resolve some dependencies in my application only if I debug my app, for example I want to use `Stetho` only for debug, not in final release, how can I achieve that?

I tried creating another folder called debug and creating `DebugApp` that extends from my App but I don't know how to run this `DebugApp`, maybe I should add something in Gradle?

```
public class DebugApp extends App {
    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();
        DebugAppInitializer.initStetho(this);
        DebugAppInitializer.initCrashczyk(this);
    }
}
```

It would be awesome if I can link it to my productFlavors

Comment: Create `src/debug/` alongside `src/main/`. Have your custom `Application` in the `src/debug/` sourceset. Have an `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the `src/debug/` sourceset that pulls in your custom `Application`.

Comment: So should I separate debug app to another module?

Comment: No, a separate sourceset within the same module. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Diagnostics/WebServer) demonstrates the idea, though in this case it is adding an activity and a service to the `debug` builds, not a custom `Application`.

Comment: Ok I see, is there a way that I can bind Android Manifest from my debug sourceType to product flavor?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question. Your mix of available build variants are not changing here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put your code like this:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
... //debug init
} else {
....//release init
}
```

**OR**

1) Create project structure like this:

[image]

2) Gradle flavors:

```
 productFlavors {
    driver {
        applicationId "android.com.driver"
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "DRIVER_SESSION", "true"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    passenger {
        applicationId "android.com.passenger"
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "DRIVER_SESSION", "false"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
sourceSets {
    passenger {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/passenger/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    driver {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/driver/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

3) Need to create differents classes  and put application name for each manifest files:

manifest in driver package ->

```
 <application
        android:name=".application.YourFirstAppInDriverPackage"
        ...
        >
```

manifest in passenger package->

```
 <application
        android:name=".application.YourSecondAppInPassengerPackage"
        ...
        >
```

4) Switch development mode between two projects:

[image]

Comment: Yes but I would prefer to separate this to another folder

Answer (score 7):

I believe you're looking for this: https://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/stetho-for-android-debug-builds-only/

TL;DR: In order to activate your DebugApp you'd need to override the manifest in your `debug` folder as follows:

```
 <manifest
    package="com.mycompany"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        tools:replace="android:name"
        android:name=".DebugApp"/>

</manifest>
```